# Saving menu position in localStorage

Tags: javascript, menu, local-storage

I created a panel div for my website that slides out of page when we click on button and come back on when we click on again.

**HTML** is simple with only panel with button for showning/hiding it.

```
<div id="panel">
    <div id="close"></div>
</div>
```

and there my **script** but storage doesn't work :

```
function storePanel(right){
    var panelData = localStorage.getItem('panel');
    if (panelData!=undefined)
       panelData=JSON.parse(panelData);
    else
       panelData={"right":"24px"};// a starting value
    panelData["top"]=top;
    panelData["right"]=right;
    localStorage.setItem('panel', JSON.stringify(panelData));
}



// hide/show panel

document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
    var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
    var right = panel.style.right;
    var icon = document.getElementById("icone");
    if (right == "24px") {
        right = "-200px";
    }
    else {
        right = "24px";
    }
    panel.style.right = right;
    storePanel(right);
};
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/remibenault/VgrS9/1/)

Comment: Wait, why do you need to save it? All your doing is moving it out of the view?

Comment: @NicholasYoung I need to save his position that if we closed the menu, on reload menu is closed.

Comment: you can use a cookie.

Comment: You never get the previous value when loading the page.

Comment: @Adjit For the moment I make a website but I will turn it as chrome extension and I need that it is saved "forever" until user clears localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `storePanel` function isn't correct. First of all, why are you using an object just to store if the panel is to the right or not? Even if you will eventually change it such that the panel can be in multiple places, you only need a number - why are you storing `panelData`? (This is just a simplification). In addition, you store the value correctly, but you never retrieve it to change the panel on page load. Your finished code should look like this (simplified):

```
// Note: I used a variable to keep track of whether the div was to the right or not
var isRight = true;

function storePanel(right) {
    // Simple
    localStorage.setItem('panel.right', right);
}

function updatePanel() {
    var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
    var right;
    if (isRight) {
        right = "-200px";
    }
    else {
        right = "24px";
    }
    panel.style.right = right;
    isRight = !isRight;
    storePanel(isRight);
}

// When the page loads, show or hide panel

isRight = localStorage.getItem("panel.right") == "false";

updatePanel();


// hide/show panel

document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
    // var icon = document.getElementById("icone");
    updatePanel();
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/YtM7y/

Comment: Thank you a lot, the truth is that I used script for saving position of div into localStorage and tried to edit it for my menu. But I've troubles to understand Javascript and Jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into problems due to blindly using javascript shorthands, like avoiding braces on the "if" statement.

```
function storePanel(right){
    var panelData = localStorage.getItem('panel');
    if (panelData) {
       panelData=JSON.parse(panelData);
    } else {
       panelData={
          "right": right || "24px", //will assign 24px if right is not set.
          "top": top
       };
    }
    localStorage.setItem('panel', panelData);
}
```

Use JSON.stringify sparingly as it might double-encode your object's quotes, thus rendering it invalid.